# [JETPACK COMPOSE]: is there a way to restart whole app programmatically?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I need a way to make my app close and opens again. Or just restart everything inside of it.
Since the issue with my app can be fixed by closing app and opening again (When creating user the loading function to firebase the collection inside user document does not load for some reason)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below code can do it:

```
 val context = LocalContext.current     
 val packageManager: PackageManager = context.packageManager
        val intent: Intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.packageName)!!
        val componentName: ComponentName = intent.component!!
        val restartIntent: Intent = Intent.makeRestartActivityTask(componentName)
        context.startActivity(restartIntent)
        Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

So... you could write ways to "restart everything", but I am going to strongly suggest **not** doing that. When building an app, you will run into edge cases. You will hit some failure states that you can't recover from. That happens. But, solving these cases by just "restarting" doesn't actually address the issue and will probably result in wonky and undesirable UX.

I would instead suggest you post here some steps to reproduce and debugging results.

- Under what circumstance/flow does this document stop loading?
- When it does happen, can you capture the call to Firebase where it is trying to load the document?

  - If so, what does that call look like?
  - Is it looking for the document in the correct place?
  - Can you show an example of the call when it fails and also what the database hierarchy looks like?
- Can you show us a snippet of code where this is failing?

Without more information, this sounds more like a race condition - you might be trying to find the document before it is actually created and not handling the error path for when the document is not found. However, we would need to do some debugging to verify.

Comment: my code uses firebase firestore. when I create a new user the collection inside the user document does not exist since there is no document inside. hence an infinite loading screen. the condition for stopping the loading is (!data.isNullOrEmpty). I tried to combat this by introducing a tutorial page where it creates a hidden document before going to mainScreen. but it still does load until I close the app and open again.  the firestore hierarchy is ( Collecton<Users> -> document<UserId> -> Collection <tasks>  -> Document<the data that is searched for by the app responsible for loading>

Comment: Why can the app not load without that last document (which I'm assuming is a task document)? Why can't you show the screen with no tasks? Also, you should get a callback from Firebase letting you know there aren't any documents. In that case, just continue without the info.

Comment: I'm pretty new to firebase. I read all I could find. watched a lot of tutorials but once I made my app following how the tutorials did I found they were pretty flawed security wise. Now when I made the App secure by changing structure. I was stuck with coming up with any idea to fix the App. And I could only find the solution of the comment above

Comment: Can you add a snippet to your question that shows where you query for the document? It sounds like you need `addOnFailureListener`, but it still isn't clear how you are trying to do load this screen and data.

Comment: Are you doing something like: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document

Comment: And if the document isn't there/isn't created, why does restarting magically work? Is it finally created at that point or is it still not created?

Comment: as I mentioned I added a new screen when you create new user where it automatically creates a hidden task thus creating the collection and the document is not null or empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246358/discussion-between-moon-sculptor-and-tj-olsen).

Answer (score 0):

I find this way to be the easiest:

```
val context = LocalContext.current as Activity

Button(
    onClick = { context.recreate() }
) {
    Text("Restart Activity")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an *Extension* function if you want to be more concise.

Create a ***Util*** folder or module in your project and add a *Context.Kt* file in it. paste the code below in.

```
fun Context.restart() {
    val packageManager = packageManager
    val intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)!!
    val componentName = intent.component!!
    val restartIntent = Intent.makeRestartActivityTask(componentName)
    startActivity(restartIntent)
    Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0)
}
```

Call the function in your composable like this :

```
val context = LocalContext.current
Button(
    modifier = Modifier
         .fillMaxWidth()
         .padding(16.dp),
    onClick = { context.restart() }
) {
    Text(
         text = "Restart",
         fontSize = 20.sp,
         fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
    )
}
```